# Does NULL-Pointer Assignment Partition has a bug?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, pointers, memory

From specs we know that

> Each process' virtual address space is split into partitions. On x86 32-Bit Windows, the partition of 0x00000000 - 0x0000FFFF (inclusive) is called NULL-Pointer Assignment Partition. This partition is set aside to help programmers catch NULL-pointer assignments. If a thread in your aprocess attempts to read from or write to a memory address in this partition, an access violoation is raised.

So if we'l create a hypothetical object with 64*1024+1 byte fields, for example

```
struct Foo {
    byte field1;
    byte field2;
    ...
    byte field65536;

    byte SomeUnexpectedData;
}* Bar = 0;

Bar->SomeUnexpectedData = 0;
```

So here we have using of unitialized null-pointer, so how does environnment avoid it? We cannot create an object larger than 64K or what?

---

C# test

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace BigObjTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var type = GetObjType();
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }

        private static Type GetObjType()
        {
            var typebuilder = GetTypeBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 65535; i++)
            {
                typebuilder.DefineField("_" + ("b" + i), typeof (byte), FieldAttributes.Private);
            }
            return typebuilder.CreateType();
        }

        private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
        {
            const string typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature
                                , TypeAttributes.Public |
                                TypeAttributes.Class |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                                , null);
            return tb;
        }
    }
}
```

It is curiously enough that CLR throws an exception if object is larger than 64K, but if write 65534 instead of 65535 it will work fine. So it's impossible in managed languages with strong type system, i guess.

Comment: This mechanism isn't intended to be foolproof, merely to help in the majority of cases.

Comment: No, it just means the pointer value itself (the address) is always larger than 64K.

Comment: Nor is that an uninitialized pointer. You're clearly initializing it to `0`. A true *indeterminate* pointer will ba all-bets-off and the purpose of the NULL pointer assignment partition would be utterly unreliable no matter how large/small your object is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a null pointer results in undefined behavior. There is no guarantee that the system detects and/or handles this. Using a protected memory page to catch most errors still seems to be a reasonable apporach.

You can certainly have objects bigger than 64kB. You may not catch some trivial mistakes using them, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of the partition.  It is so that if a pointer is incorrectly assigned:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p = 4;
```

then the system can catch it, rather than have it do something horrible.  The 64K limit means that it can catch it for values up to 64K.  Because:

```
p = 56678455;
```

Might be a 'valid' address area but still be a wrong assignment.  It can't check for everything.